# cmake - undefined reference to

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I am new to `cmake` and know this question has been asked before, but still cannot find what I am doing wrong. I have an external library with folders `/include` and `lib`. The `/include` folder contains all the headers (`.h`) and the `/lib` folder contains all the source (`.c`) files.

In my project I have this `CMakeList.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(FirstAttempt)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set (EXTRA_LIBS "D:\\libtrading")

include_directories(${EXTRA_LIBS}/include)
link_directories(${EXTRA_LIBS}/include)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(FirstAttempt ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries (FirstAttempt  ${EXTRA_LIBS}/lib)
```

I know that I have to use `target_link_libraries` to link the source files of the library to my project, but certainly something is missing, but what? I am still receiving the error `undefined reference to xxxxxx`.

The library I am trying to include in my project is https://github.com/libtrading/libtrading.

Answer (score 2):

As you know, we need all source files to compile. So we need to point out Cmake know where/what are source files.

I think you should add all sources files like this

```
file(GLOB SOURCES_FILES "lib/*.c" main.cpp)
```

to add all .c files.

Or, you can add all lib/*.c files separately

```
file(SOURCES_FILES_LIBS "lib/*.c")
set(SOURCES_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(FirstAttempt ${SOURCES_FILES_LIBS} ${SOURCES_FILES})
```

Comment: Does the `file` command uses a relative or absolute directory?

Comment: Seems like I would need to add the library as a sub-directory of the main project. Would this be the only way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'll try.

First, seems that you are calling `link_directories()` on the folder which contains header files, while [it should be used in order to specify the path where to search libraries for](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html).

Second, `target_link_libraries()` [takes the absolute path](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) of the shared/static library file as the second argument, while you are passing the directory path (well, it seems so).

`target_link_libraries()` doesn't link to the "source files of the library", - it links to the compiled shared/static library blob.

And, I would also recommend you to save the name of the executable to the variable so that you wouldn't be able to mistype the target name, like so:

```
set(TARGET FirstAttempt)
add_executable(${TARGET})
```